# Timetable events packing

Tags: javascript, packing, timetable

I'm working on timetable for school purposes. I receive time-ordered list of events and my goal is to draw them on timeline. The problem is that some event overlaps another (as shown on the picture below). What I want to do is to "pack" this events into the smallest space possible. [This is single day with overlapping events.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boImo.png)

First picture shows what I managed to do so far. As seen on picture, rectangles do not intersect each other and fill free space nicely. BUT I didn't manage to come up with reasonable algorithm for ordering.[Second picture shows how events should be ordered.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rl7dY.png)

This are two conditions, which make this problem different from classic packing problem:

1. Events has given x-coordinates (defined by beginning and end).
2. Events has fixed width, height is arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

This Problem reminds me a little bit of file system fragmentation problem. Easy solutions would be to implement one of the famous algorithm e.g. first-fit or best-fit.

But I guess you want the best solution. That's why I'd suggest implementing a [backtracking algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking). Be aware that I can cause long runtimes but I think this doesn't really matter in your context.